# Setting an 'active' class on hover and keeping the class of active on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a problem where I'm wanting to set a class of 'active' on an item when it's hovered over. When I hover away from the item I still want the 'active' class to stay. Only when another item is hovered over, will the 'active' class be removed from the original hover and be added to the current hover.

I'm using toggleClass but that's not preserving the class when I move my mouse away from the item.

JSfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/HzQ9d/157/

```
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
</ul>

$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, remove the class from all `li.active` elements using [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add it onto the currently hovered item using mouseover.

```js
$('ul').on('mouseover', 'li', function() {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul li {
  margin: 60px 0;
}

.active {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
</ul>
```

This will work even if you dynamically add more `<li>`s to the `<ul>`

Comment: So simple! I ended up doing it this way - http://jsfiddle.net/HzQ9d/160/ - but your answer seems better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `toggle` use `addClass` & `removeClass`. On hovering another element just remove the `active` class from the element where it was previously added

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  $('ul >li').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test 1</li>
  <li>test 2</li>
  <li>test 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/82op2tv0/
Use siblings

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Use the event mouseover together with siblings?

```
$('li').on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```